# Problems in java TCP socket close and reopen

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

i am writing an application in java swing which uses socket to connect to python agent, send and receives data over the socket and closes,

now when i try to reopen the socket, it gives me error,

i tried checking socket status after socket is closed, i stuck on following problem

```
clientSocket //is my java socket,

clientSocket.isConnected() //returns true
clientSocket.isBound() //returs true
clientSocket.isClosed() //return true
```

can anybody help, how can i ensure what is status of my socket?

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to reopen a closed socket. Instead, reinitialize it calling the same constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new socket each time. When you close the socket the file descriptor is released and the socket is no longer available.It cannot be reopened.
From the jdk:

> Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket needs to be created.